# How to handle the lifetime of a buffer in a generic function deserializing from a file?

Tags: generics, rust, traits, lifetime

The following minimal example reads a struct from disk just fine:

```
extern crate bincode;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;

use bincode::deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Thing {
    something: u64,
}

fn load_thing_from_file(file_path: &str) -> Thing {
    // unwrap instead of actual error handling for brevity of this example.
    let mut file = File::open(file_path).unwrap();
    let mut buffer: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    file.read_to_end(&mut buffer).unwrap();
    let result: Thing = deserialize(&buffer[..]).unwrap();
    return result;
}

fn main() {
    let t = load_thing_from_file("thing.bin");
    println!("{}", t.something);
}
```

However when I try to make the load function generic, like so:

```
extern crate bincode;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;

use bincode::deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Thing {
    something: u64
}

fn load_from_file<'de, T: serde::Deserialize<'de>>(file_path: &str) -> T {
    // unwrap instead of actual error handling for brevity of this example.
    let mut file = File::open(file_path).unwrap();
    let mut buffer: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    file.read_to_end(&mut buffer).unwrap();
    let result: T = deserialize(&buffer[..]).unwrap();
    return result;
}

fn main() {
    let t = load_from_file::<Thing>("thing.bin");
    println!("{}", t.something);
}
```

I get:

```
error[E0597]: `buffer` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:20:34
   |
20 |     let result: T = deserialize(&buffer[..]).unwrap();
   |                                  ^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
21 |     return result;
22 | }
   | - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'de as defined on the function body at 15:19...
  --> src/main.rs:15:19
   |
15 | fn load_from_file<'de, T: serde::Deserialize<'de>>(file_path: &str) -> T {
   |                   ^^^
```

How can I fix this so that the compiler understands things are OK?

Comment: Ah, I should have read this answer even after I figured out the solution for my initial problem, since you already had anticipated the next problem I'd have. Thanks again. And now [it works fine](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/cc6e84f687a8e7b35f6789a1f36a15c3).

Comment: TL;DR the duplicate: `fn load_from_file<T: serde::de::DeserializeOwned>(file_path: &str) -> T`

Comment: I notice from your error message that you are still using Rust 2015; I encourage you to upgrade [to Rust 2018](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2018/12/06/Rust-1.31-and-rust-2018.html); it will make certain things much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the remark! I now updated. The [new error](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/87eb6d424eefd752f8e9e4790c408d0e) looks nicer formatted than the old one. I'll now read what else the new version brings. :)